# Generic Collection copying method

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got this useful little method that uses reflection to copy a single class instance. It has the advantage of letting you copy between classes that are not exactly the same, just copying the matching properties. I use it a lot.

```
public static void ObjectCopy(object source, object target)
{
    if (source != null && target != null)
    {
        foreach (var prop in target.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var FromProp = source.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            if (FromProp != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(target, FromProp.GetValue(source));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've now got a requirement to do a similar thing, but with a collection, ie an ObservableCollection or List. I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in a generic routine. I can call the old routine from within the new one to do the collection item copying but handling the collection itself is what I'm struggling with.

Any ideas?

---

I need to be able to copy collection of different (but similar) classes. My example being an ObservableCollection into an ObservableCollection. They have common properties but also some differences.

Sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: You effectively need to join the two collections (existing + updated) and then use your method for each pairing.

Comment: @Luaan it has a lot of to with generic programming, nothing to do with polymorphic type generics they have just mistaken the nature of the tag they included

Comment: Apologies for the wrong tag - I've removed it.

Comment: @Luaan and my point is that helping someone understand why they have made a mistake helps them to avoid making it again as well as making them more willing to correct it as they realise why it was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it. Only works on collections.

```
public static void ObjectCollection<TC, TK>(ICollection source, TC target)
    where TC : class, ICollection<TK>, new()
    where TK : class, new()
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var copiedItem = new TK();
        ObjectCopy(item, copiedItem);
        target.Add(copiedItem);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Data { public string Test { get; set; } }
public class Data2 { public string Test { get; set; } }

var source = new Data[3] {
    new Data { Test = "1" },
    new Data { Test = "2" },
    new Data { Test = "3" }
};
var target = new List<Data2>();
ObjectCollection<List<Data2>, Data2>(source, target);
```

Comment: This is really close - unfortunately it doesn't work if the collections are of different types. I'm trying to copy an ObservableCollection<PressureTaps> into an ObservableCollection<EditablePressureTaps>. They have common properties but also some differences.

Comment: @RobMarsh Do you mean that the collections have differences, or the items in the collection? The copying of the items in the collection is done by your `ObjectCopy` method.

Comment: @RobMarsh Can you specify exactly what is not working?

Comment: I get the following error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Definitions.VMEntities.EditablePressureTap>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DBAccess.Model.PressureTap>''. I'm not familiar with the generics code in the method, so I'm not sure how to tweak it.

Comment: @RobMarsh Can you show the line of code that generates that exception? The generic parameter that you have to specify is the target-collection-type.

Comment: I've used it like this: Common.CollectionObjectCopy <ObservableCollection<PressureTap>, ObservableCollection<EditablePressureTap>>(oldPressureTaps, PressureTapCollection); I've renamed the method and put it in a common library, but thats the only change I've made.

Comment: The usage is incorrect. It should be: CollectionObjectCopy<ObservableCollection<EditablePressureTap>, EditablePressureTap>(..., ...);

Comment: Aha! That explains it, it works now. I need to read up on how this works... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following to join together two existing collections of different type:

```
public static void MapCollections<T1, T2, TKey>(IEnumerable<T1> target, IEnumerable<T2> values,
        Func<T1, TKey> targetKeySelector, Func<T2, TKey> valueKeySelector)
{
    foreach (var pair in target.Join(values, targetKeySelector, valueKeySelector, (t, v) => new { target = t, value = v}))
    {
        ObjectCopy(pair.value, pair.target);
    }
}
```

You might need to work in some additional constraints to manage duplicate keys etc.